# Assembly Language While Loop

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, segmentation-fault

I have been working on writing a compiler that translates into assembly language. I am having a problem with my while loops. No matter how simple I make them in my original program, they always give me segmentation faults.

here is the code for the program I'm compiling into assembly language:

```
start
    start
        int x.
        x = 0.
        repeat[x <= 5] //while x is less than or equal to 5 print out x
        start
            print x. 
        finish
    finish
finish
```

Here's the assembly language code that's generated:

```
PUSH
LOAD x
STACKW 0
LOAD 0
STACKW 0

L0:
LOAD 5
STORE V0
STACKR 0
SUB V0
BRPOS L1

STACKR 0
STORE V1
WRITE V1

BR L0
L1: NOOP
POP

STOP
V0 0
V1 0
x 0
```

The logic seems ok to me, but I'm getting a segmentation fault when I run this assembly language code. Can anyone tell me what might be causing this? Thanks!

Comment: can you explain some of your assembly syntax? what's BRPOS and NOOP?

Comment: "BRPOS arg" 1, jumps to arg if ACC >0 and "NOOP" means No operation, so basically do nothing. The while loop jumps to NOOP when x > 5.

Comment: OK, your compiler compiles <your-language> source code to **some** assembly code and that work as expected, good. So, **what is the assembly language syntax you use?** I mean, what is the CPU architecture you are targeting and what is the assembler you use to assemble the assembly code generated by your compiler? And **how do you assemble and link the assembly code generated by your compiler?** I mean, what are the exact assembler and linker commands and parameters if the assembler and linker are executed from command line? If the assembler and linker are executed from some IDE, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turned out all I needed was to put NOOP after "L0:" and that got rid of the segmentation fault and worked correctly. So the final program was as follows:

```
PUSH
LOAD x
STACKW 0
LOAD 0
STACKW 0

L0: NOOP
LOAD 5
STORE V0
STACKR 0
SUB V0
BRPOS L1

STACKR 0
STORE V1
WRITE V1

BR L0
L1: NOOP
POP

STOP
V0 0
V1 0
x 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any explanation on the instructions this is hard to answer.
But...
I don't see any ADD's; so how then do you increment the value that gets displayed?
And...
Every iteration of the loop starts with LOAD 5. Shouldn't you place this outside/before the loop?